# Where do i have to put the AllowXsltScript true to allow scripting in my xlst

Tags: sharepoint-2010, scripting, xls

I'm having problem to allow scripting in my xls file. I'm getting the "security settings do not allow the execution of script code within this style-sheet" message. Looking for a solution i found that the AllowXsltScript makes the trick but it is false by default. The problem is I don't know where to put that code to set it true.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using Sharepoint Designer with xlst v 1.0.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f90503c-2e7d-490a-95fb-b945c6ee5014/security-settings-do-not-allow-the-execution-of-script-code-within-this-stylesheet?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Yes I did i couldn'd find a solution :( I am newbie at this btw

Answer (score 2):

The property is not set as an attribute within the XSLT file. It is set on the XSLT object in the code which utilizes the file. In VB6, the code would look like the code shown below.

```
Dim objXSLTTransform As New DOMDocument60                    ‘XSLT file*

Call objXSLTTransform.setProperty("AllowXsltScript", True)
```